# While - Java Exercicio

Tags: java, eclipse

Boa noite, estava realizando um exercício com a estrutura while com este código a seguir:

System.out.println(“Informe o sexo: f - femninino, m - masculino”);

sexo = scan.nextLine();

while (!sexo.equalsIgnoreCase(“f”) || !sexo.equalsIgnoreCase(“m”)) {

System.out.println("Sexo inválido, insira novamente: ");

sexo = scan.nextLine();
}

Na impressão do console, o Sysout ("Sexo inválido, insira novamente: "); está aparecendo antes mesmo de eu inserir qualquer letra e as letras ‘M’ e ‘F’ não estão sendo consideradas, alguém me ajudaria?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -1):

Olá, você está validando o while errado, tente mudar "||" para "&&".

```
package Main;
    
    import java.util.Scanner;
    
    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            
            String sexo;
            
            do {
                System.out.println("Informe o sexo: f - feminino, m - masculino");
                sexo = scanner.next();
                
            } while (!sexo.equalsIgnoreCase("f") && !sexo.equalsIgnoreCase("m"));
            
            if (sexo.equalsIgnoreCase("f")) {
                System.out.println("Você escolheu feminino");
            } else if (sexo.equalsIgnoreCase("m")) {
                System.out.println("Você escolheu masculino");
            }
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).